# Error "Cannot invoke" en etiqueta XML

Tags: java, xml, nullpointerexception

Hola el broblema es que tengo una etiqueta en un xml que existe en algunos nodos  si el dato no existe la etiqueta no esta "**dateOfBirth**" asi que cuando no lo encuentra en mi recorrido me lanza el error

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.w3c.dom.Node.getTextContent()" because the return value of "org.w3c.dom.NodeList.item(int)" is null**

me gustaria saber como regresar el valor como un null directamente y que no termine la ejecucion

```
  try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document documento = builder.parse(new File(path));
            NodeList listaentidades = documento.getElementsByTagName("sdnEntry");
            NodeList list2 = documento.getElementsByTagName("sdnList");

            Node node2 = list2.item(0);
            Element element2 = (Element) node2;
            publish_date = element2.getElementsByTagName("Publish_Date").item(0).getTextContent();
            record_count = element2.getElementsByTagName("Record_Count").item(0).getTextContent();

            System.out.println("Fecha de publicacion : " + publish_date + " record_count: " + record_count + " ");

            for (int i = 0; i < listaentidades.getLength(); i++) {

                Node nodo = listaentidades.item(i);

                if (nodo.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element e = (Element) nodo;
                    NodeList hijos = e.getChildNodes();
                    String tipo = e.getElementsByTagName("sdnType").item(0).getTextContent();
                    
                    String caso= tipo.trim().toLowerCase();
                    System.out.println(caso);
                    


                    if (caso.equals("entity")) {
                        

                        
                        vuid = e.getElementsByTagName("uid").item(0).getTextContent();
                        lastname = e.getElementsByTagName("lastName").item(0).getTextContent();
//                        firstname = e.getElementsByTagName("firstName").item(0).getTextContent();
//                        fn = e.getElementsByTagName("dateOfBirth").item(0).getTextContent();
                        System.out.println(vuid + " " + lastname + " ");
                        

                    } else if (caso.equals("individual")) {
                        System.out.println("no");
                        
                        vuid = e.getElementsByTagName("uid").item(0).getTextContent();
                        lastname = e.getElementsByTagName("lastName").item(0).getTextContent();
                        firstname = e.getElementsByTagName("firstName").item(0).getTextContent();
                        fn = e.getElementsByTagName("dateOfBirth").item(0).getTextContent();
                        System.out.println(vuid + " " + lastname + " " );
                        System.out.println(fn);

                    }
                    

                    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

me ha funcionado revisando la longitud del NodeList y si es mayor a 0 osea si existe.

```
 NodeList fnlmnts =e.getElementsByTagName("dateOfBirth");
                       if(fnlmnts.getLength()>0){
                           System.out.println("largo"+fnlmnts.getLength());
                           fn=fnlmnts.item(0).getTextContent();
                       
                   }
```